# Negation of "For all odd integers $n$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> For all odd integers $n$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$.

I negated using De Morgan's laws. Let $O(n)$ be "$n$ is odd" and $N(n, k)$ "$2k + 1 = n$", then
$$\neg(\forall n \exists k [O(n) \to N(n,k)])\\
\exists n \neg\exists k [O(n) \to N(n,k)]\\
\exists n \forall k \neg [O(n) \to N(n,k)]\\
\exists n \forall k \neg [\neg O(n) \lor N(n,k)]\\
\exists n \forall k O(n) \land \neg N(n,k)\\
$$
Therefore the negation is

> There is at least one $n$ that is odd, and for all $k$ such that $n\neq2k+1$

Is that the correct result?

Comment: That is correct, though contractions are frowned upon in formal mathematical statements.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Can you clarify, what do you mean by contraction?

Comment: An English contraction: "there's" $\to$ "there is". But it's a minor thing.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I see; thanks.

Comment: I have changed $x$ to $n$ in your question as I suppose that was a typo. (There is no $x$ anywhere.)

Comment: @TMM yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> For all odd integers $n$, there does **not** exist any integer $k$ such that $n=2k+1$

Comment: The negation of "for all" is "there exists"

Answer (score 0):

Your sentences do not reflect the logical expressions. You should have started from

$$\forall n: O(n),\exists k: N(n,k),$$

turning to

$$\exists n: O(n),\forall k: \lnot N(n,k).$$